# How to include extra files when building a war?

Tags: grails

I am trying to add a dir (`garils-app/store`) to my war like this on my `BuildConfig.groovy`.

```
grails.war.resources = {stagingDir,args->
    copy(file: "grails-app/store/**", toFile: "${stagingDir}/store")
}
```

But when I try to build the war file I am getting this error:

---

`| Error WAR packaging error: Warning: Could not find file  /home/codehx/git/appName/grails-app/store/** to copy`.

It looks like grails is not considering the `**` as wild cards, am I having any error? Or if it is not  possible how can I recursively copy the content of `store` dir to my war file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Given that the `grails.war.resources` is an `AntBuilder` you can use any proper `AntBuilder` expressions to include additional resources. In older versions of `AntBuilder` the `**` notation did work, but in later versions of `AntBuilder` the preferred method is:

```
grails.war.resources = { stagingDir, args ->
    copy(todir: "${stagingDir}/store") {
        fileset(dir: "grails-app/store")
    }
}
```